# If $G$ is a $r-regular$ graph and $K(G) = 1$ (vertex connectivity) show that the edge connectivity λ(G) $<=$ $r/2$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

My attempt is that G have at least one cut vertex and I know that I have to divide the edges of v in two groups but I don't know how to show that the edge connectivity have to be less or equal than r/2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the cut-vertex of $G$. Then $G-v$ has at least two connected components. Since the number of edges incident with $v$ is $r$ then there exists a component for which there are at most $r/2$ edges that connect $v$ to that component. Removing those edges will disconnect $G$ into exactly two components.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't see how exists a component for which there are at most r/2 that connect $v$ to that component.

Comment: Suppose there are $x$ edges that connect $v$ to one component and $y$ edges that connect $v$ to the other component. Now we can't have both $x>r/2$ and $y>r/2$ and have $x+y=r$, so it must be that either $x\le r/2$ or $y\le r/2$, right?

Comment: Ohh! Thank you very much bro. Now I get it.

Comment: In general, if we know $G$ is $r$-regular and the removal of a vertex $v$ results in $G$ being broken up into $k$ components then $\lambda(G)\le r/k$ with a very similar argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.